# Protected Access Modifier

Tags: java, variables, protected

I have the following two piece of code :

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.akshu.multithreading;

/**
 * @author akshu
 *
 */
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    protected  int b;   

    private int a;
    @Override
    public void run() {

        super.run();

        System.out.println("int a:"+a);
    }

}



-----------


package com.akshu.utility;

import com.akshu.multithreading.MyThread;

public class MyUtility extends MyThread{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MyThread th1 = new MyThread();
        int d =th1.b;  // line1
        System.out.println("int d"+d);
    }

}
```

with the above files of code i am trying to understand purpose of protected access modifier.  In the file MyUtility , I am trying to refer variable b of class MyThread.But its giving me below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The field MyThread.b is not visibilty.
```

My concern is variable b should be accessible from subclass as i have already extended the Mythread. But it is giving me compile time error. Also when i declare this variable as static in my superclass i was able to access it directly .So what wrong i am doing when i am trying to access via instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method main is not explicitly part of MyThread - if you would implement another function, e.g. prtintB(), you could use the direct access with the "." operator. To access it from main you have to write a getter function.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access protected properties from an instance. You can only access them in inheriting class. In this line-

```
MyThread  th1  = new MyThread (); int  d  = th1 . b ;
```

you are actually trying to access a protected property from an instance  `th1`.

Comment: OP is actually trying to access aprotected property from an instance  `th1`.

Comment: :Thanks , i got your point.I was mixing two different visibility together . One for instance and other for inheritance .

Answer (score 2):

From [Kathy Sierra's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071591060) great book, explaining the misunderstanding of `protected` scope:

> But what does it mean for a subclass-outside-the-package to have
>   access to a superclass (parent) member? It means the subclass inherits
>   the member. It does not, however, mean the
>   subclass-outside-the-package can access the member using a reference
>   to an instance of the superclass. In other words, protected =
>   inheritance. Protected does not mean that the subclass can treat the
>   protected superclass member as though it were public. So if the
>   subclass-outside-the-package gets a reference to the superclass (by,
>   for example, creating an instance of the superclass somewhere in the
>   subclass' code), the subclass cannot use the dot operator on the
>   superclass reference to access the protected member. To a
>   subclass-outside-the-package, a protected member might as well be
>   default (or even private), when the subclass is using a reference to
>   the superclass. **The subclass can see the protected member only through
>   inheritance.**

Thus, in your case, you try to use a reference to access a protected member outside parent's class package:

```
MyThread th1 = new MyThread();
int d =th1.b;  //b cannot be reached !
```

Answer (score 1):

Java lang specification section 6.6.2.1 will tell you the truth :

> If the access is by a field access expression `E.Id`, where `E` is a Primary expression, or by a method invocation expression `E.Id(. . .)`, where `E` is a Primary expression, then the access is permitted if and only if the type of `E` is `S` or a subclass of `S`.

Here `MyThread` is `C`, `MyUtility` is `S` and b is `Id`. So in a MyUtility ionstance you cannot use a reference to an instance pf `MyThread` to access its `b`